# Combining two observable sources filtering by one first observable property

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

Having an observable emitting a list of users with the next content:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mary",
        "status": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Peter",
        "status": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Susan",
        "status": "Active"
    }
]
```

And I have another observable returning the extended user data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "authorizations: 20
}
```

I use the detail of each user in an specific details page, but I would like to combine part of the detail in the users list and obtain the next result and only filter by the status **Active**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "status": "Active",
        "authorizations": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Susan",
        "status": "Active",
        "authorizations": 10
    }
]
```

It is possible to use some filtering operator and combine those results without use two subscriptions?

Tried the following code but, would be a better or simplified way to do it?

```
import { of, Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, mergeAll, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

type State = 'Active' | 'Inactive';

type User = { id: number; name: string; status: State };
type UserDetail = { id: number; authorizations: number };
type UserWithAuthorizations = User & UserDetail

const users: User[] = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mary",
        "status": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Peter",
        "status": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Susan",
        "status": "Active"
    }
]

const authorizations: UserDetail[] = [
  { id: 1, authorizations: 20 },
  { id: 2, authorizations: 5 },
  { id: 3, authorizations: 30 },
  { id: 4, authorizations: 10 },
];

const getAuthorizationsByUser= (userId: number): Observable<Partial<UserWithAuthorizations>>  => {
  const users$ = of(users)
  const authorizations$ = of(authorizations)
  return combineLatest([users$, authorizations$]).pipe(
    map(res => {
    const user = res[0].find(u => u.id === userId)
    const { authorizations } = res[1].find(a => a.id === userId)
    return {
      ...user,
      authorizations
    }
  }))
};

const fetchUsersWithAuthorizations = () => of(users);


fetchUsersWithAuthorizations()
  .pipe(
    mergeAll<User>(),
    filter((user) => user.status === "Active"),
    mergeMap((user) => getAuthorizationsByUser(user.id))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: why are you wrapping `of(users)` and `of(authorizations)` in `getAuthorizationsByUser`? Is it to mock the fact that you get that data as observables in the first place? Or no reason? Because if not then it could be simplified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is the following:

```js
// utility to transform an array into a dictionary based on some key
// I'll explain why in a second
const toDictionary = <
  Obj extends Record<string | number | symbol, any>,
  Key extends keyof Obj
>(
  arr: Obj[],
  key: Key
): Record<Obj[Key], Obj> =>
  arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr[key]] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<Obj[Key], Obj>);

const fetchUsers = () => of(users);
const fetchAuthorizations = () => of(authorizations);

combineLatest([
  fetchUsers(),
  fetchAuthorizations().pipe(
    // here, we transform the authorizations array into a dictionary
    // with the ID as key, so that later on we can access an authorization
    // based on an ID. This will save us to iterate on the authorization array
    // for each of the users which is more efficient. Note that we also do it
    // here instead of doing it later so that if the `fetchUsers()` was to be replaced by an observable
    // that can emit multiple times, we'd not make that transformation if it emits
    // we only do it when necessary: Only when the authorizations observable changes
    map((authorizations) => toDictionary(authorizations, 'id'))
  ),
])
  .pipe(
    map(([users, authorizations]): UserWithAuthorizations[] =>
      users
        .map((user) => ({
          ...user,
          authorizations: authorizations[user.id]?.authorizations,
        }))
        .filter((user) => user.status === 'Active')
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See a [live demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wbms3j?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

EDIT: I saw your comment on the post only after answering the above.

Based on the fact that you can only fetch `authorizations` individually, I've got 2 options for you:

1. You want only 1 emission, including all the users with their permissions

```js
const usersWithAUthorizations$: Observable<UserWithAuthorizations[]> =
  fetchUsers().pipe(
    mergeMap((users) =>
      forkJoin(
        users
          .filter((user) => user.status === 'Active')
          .map((user) =>
            fetchAuthorizations(user.id).pipe(
              map((authorizations) => ({
                ...user,
                ...authorizations,
              }))
            )
          )
      )
    )
  );
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-d7drhx?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

2. You want to get all the intermediate emission, meaning that each time we get the authorization for a given user, we'd emit a temporary result with all the previous responses + the current, etc until we treated all of them

```js
const usersWithAUthorizations$: Observable<UserWithAuthorizations[]> =
  fetchUsers().pipe(
    mergeMap((users) =>
      users
        .filter((user) => user.status === 'Active')
        .map((user) =>
          fetchAuthorizations(user.id).pipe(
            map((authorizations) => ({
              ...user,
              ...authorizations,
            }))
          )
        )
    ),
    mergeAll(),
    scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], [] as UserWithAuthorizations[])
  );
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-m8oaaw?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it all in a single combine latest?

```js
const { of, map, combineLatest } = rxjs;

const users = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mary",
        "status": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Peter",
        "status": "Inactive"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Susan",
        "status": "Active"
    }
]

const authorizations = [
  { id: 1, authorizations: 20 },
  { id: 2, authorizations: 5 },
  { id: 3, authorizations: 30 },
  { id: 4, authorizations: 10 },
];

const users$ = of(users)
const authorizations$ = of(authorizations)

const activeUsersWithAuthorizations$ = combineLatest([users$, authorizations$]).pipe(
  map(([users, authorizations]) =>
    users
      .filter((user) => user.status === 'Active')
      .map((user) => ({
        ...user,
        authorizations: authorizations.find((a) => a.id === user.id)?.authorizations,
      }))
  )
);

activeUsersWithAuthorizations$.subscribe(activeUsersWithAuthorizations => {
  console.log(activeUsersWithAuthorizations);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Because I don't have the request to get the full list of authorizations, I only have the request for the details of each authorization, then I thought in flat the first observable to link authorization to each inner user. With the getAuthorizationsByUser() function was emulating the other needed observable